# Calculate DAC output as decimal value

Tags: arm, microcontroller, keil, 8051

I'm confused with the method of calculating DAC output as decimal value. I'm using DAC7741. The voltage I need to estimate is called Vint. The below code is a sample I refer. But I don't know why voltage = DAC_buf *3052 ?? I checked the DAC7741 datasheet but didn't see any clue of 3052. Please explain to me how we can get that formula. Thank you!

```
                unsigned long DAC_buf   =0x0000; 
                unsigned char idata Vint_H              _at_ 0xB3;
                unsigned char idata Vint_L              _at_ 0xB4;

                DAC_buf += Vint_H;
                DAC_buf = DAC_buf << 8;
                DAC_buf += Vint_L;

                if(Vint_H<0x80)
                {   
                    DAC_buf = 0x8000-DAC_buf;
                    voltage = DAC_buf *3052;
                    voltage_ten_thousand = (voltage%100000000)/10000000;
                    voltage_thousand = (voltage%10000000)/1000000;
                    voltage_hundred = (voltage%1000000)/100000 ;
                    voltage_ten = (voltage%100000)/10000 ;
                    voltage_unit = (voltage%10000)/1000;
                }
                else
                {
                    DAC_buf = DAC_buf- 0x8000;
                    voltage = DAC_buf *3052;
                    voltage_ten_thousand = (voltage%100000000)/10000000;
                    voltage_thousand =     (voltage%10000000)/1000000;
                    voltage_hundred =      (voltage%1000000)/100000 ;
                    voltage_ten =          (voltage%100000)/10000 ;
                    voltage_unit =         (voltage%10000)/1000;
                }
```

Another voltage I need to calculate from a power IC (LTC2606).

```
voltage = 13050- OVSS_buf*100;   // OVSS_buf is the hex value assigned to the                      power IC
```

I got that formula after tried & error several times. Even though I got correct result to display on the monitor, I still don't know how to get the correct formula. I checked LTC2606 the formula of Vout = (k/2^16)*Vcc.    Vcc = 3V

I would appreciate if someone can explain to me the way of calculating both voltages I mentioned above.

Comment: We'll need more information than this, I think.  What's the reference voltage input to the DAC7741, for example?

Comment: the close bracket after your if-statement is missing!

Comment: Dear @cooperised: reference voltage input to the DAC7741 is 10V.

Comment: 3052 is approximately 1e8 / 2^15.

Comment: I'm still confused by the question.  Why would you need to calculate the output voltage of a DAC?  Surely you're *setting* the output voltage elsewhere in your code?

Comment: @starblue : How could you get the exponent 15 and e8? Please explain more clearly. Thank you!

Comment: @cooperised : Because I need to display the voltage value from it. E.x. I set in initial hex value for data input (called Vdata) maybe Vdata_input = 0x10 corresponds to 1V.
After the adjustment algorithm finished, the Vdata would be updated to a new value corresponding to 5V. I need to display it.

Comment: @starblue : As I understand, you get 2^15 from the number of DAC data input  (16 pins). But I don't know why you get 1e8?

Comment: If you don't know the relationship between the value you're using to set the DAC and the output voltage it's producing, I'm not sure how any of your code is going to work. :-/

Comment: @starblue 's comment was an observation, I think, that multiplication by 3052 is approximately equivalent to multiplying by 100000000 and dividing by 32768 (2^15).  The effect of this will be to convert the measured value from a range of 0-65535 to a range of 0-199999999.  *Why* this is done in your code snippet is a good question, but we can only guess, because you didn't write the code yourself and you didn't say where you got it from either.

Comment: Actually 0x8000 is subtracted in some way (the 0x8000-x looks a bit strange) before multiplying, so overall you get a range -100000000...+10000000. The division/modulo after that extracts the five leading decimal digits. The value is in mV (10000mV = 10V).

Comment: @starblue Looks like for some reason the value is being stored in an unsigned variable and then treated as though it's signed (0x8000 is the sign bit).  Really weird code TBH, it would be informative to know where it came from.

Comment: @cooperised It looks like the unsigned value is put together from the raw values in two 8-bit GPIO registers which feed into the DAC. I looked at its data sheet, it is sane, it has 16 bit parallel input and the analog output just increases according to the digital value. It seems that between MCU and DAC the bits are inverted, hence the strangeness. The sign-magnitude representation is for the decimal output.

Comment: @starblue Agreed, the datasheet is sane. The DAC is capable of operating dual-rail, but you are correct that the raw value is always unsigned regardless of the mode. I don't think anything's being inverted though. My best guess is that the DAC is in dual-rail mode so raw values above 0x8000 represent positive voltages, with those below being negative. In this context the code above (somewhat clumsily) returns the absolute value of the DAC output voltage, scaled to a maximum of roughly 1e8 as you found. Still not sure why though, and OP is not providing any more information!

Comment: @cooperised Yes, you are right, the bits are not inverted. Now all makes sense. Scaling to 1e8 is a bit small actually, since you multiply by 3052 and then divide by 1000 for the last digit, the last digit will make jumps of 3 or 4. Less would be even worse, for 1e7 the last digit would make jumps of 30 or 31. 1e9 would be better IMHO, but closer to overflow of signed 32 bit numbers at ~2e9, so maybe the writer of the code was afraid of that and rather accepted an inaccurate last digit.